# PySpark: why does my application ignore one of the executors?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a cluster composed by a master and two executors. In the spark master application I can see both executors are alive, but when I start a spark application only one of them is used, and the other (always the same one) is ignored.

This is how I configure my spark session:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("spark://localhost:master-ip")\
.appName("Spark Application")\
.config("spark.executor.memory", "512m")\
.config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")\
.config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled", "false")\
.getOrCreate()
```

what could the problem be?

Comment: spark will only use the nodes when necessary. in other times it will have only the master running.

Comment: One of the executor is the master if the `--mode=cluster`

Comment: @samkart Oh ok, I didn't know that, but still I think both nodes are needed. The program can barely do anything because it says that the task size is too large, but from the Spark UI I see that there still is just one executor besides the driver.. Am I wrong to think that the task size problem would be resolved if both nodes were used?

Comment: You can specify master config separately than executor. Master config can be smaller i.e. less number of cores and memory. You can increase number of executors. Just make sure you aren't doing a step which pulls the entire result into the master. If everything is distributed, i.e. all actions happen on the executors, it should work. Also increase number of partitions of your data.